# performing login to my university student portal via app

Tags: android, json, httpclient

I wanted to connect to the student portal of my university with my app and access certain information from the website like the current result. so I have written this code so far I am having trouble logging in. Whenever I pressed login button the app crashes.. I know something is wrong with my code so I will be really thankful if you guys help me fix the problem.. here is the url of the my student profile.

http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/

and here is the code which I have written so far....

java file

```
package com.example.ebad.testing;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button login;
    TextView Enrollement,password,E;



    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Enrollement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Enrollment);
        password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        E = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);

        login.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String GMAIL_CONTACTS = "http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/PersonalInfo.aspx";
                        String GMAIL_LOGIN = "http://111.68.99.8/StudentProfile/";
                        String message_e = E.toString();
                        message_e += "";

                        String Enrollement_e = Enrollement.toString();
                        String password_e  = password.toString();

                        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(GMAIL_LOGIN);

                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00_Body_ENROLLMENTTextBox_tb", Enrollement_e));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00_Body_PasswordTextBox_tb", password_e));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ctl00_Body_LoginButton", "login"));

                        try {
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = null;
                        try {
                            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        message_e +=response.getStatusLine();
                        E.setText(message_e);

                        Log.d(TAG, "response stat code " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

                        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400) {

                            String cookie = response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie")
                                    .getValue();
                            Log.d(TAG, "cookie: " + cookie);

                            // get the contacts page
                            HttpGet getContacts = new HttpGet(GMAIL_CONTACTS);
                            getContacts.setHeader("Cookie", cookie);
                            try {
                                response = httpClient.execute(getContacts);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            InputStream ins = null;
                            try {
                                ins = response.getEntity().getContent();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    ins));

                            String inputLine;
                            try {
                                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, " " + inputLine);
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            try {
                                in.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Response error: "
                                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                        }


                    }
                }
        );


    }








    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and this is the xml file...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter the Enrollement"
        android:id="@+id/Enrollment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:hint="Enter the Password"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Enrollment"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="82dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat is here

```
08-06 00:43:58.542    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
08-06 00:44:03.139    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
08-06 00:44:03.142    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c42500, tid 1904
08-06 00:44:03.203    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
08-06 00:44:03.473    1904-1917/com.example.ebad.testing I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3295(250KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 23% free, 872KB/1135KB, paused 39.997ms total 200.658ms
08-06 00:44:03.539    1904-1917/com.example.ebad.testing W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 66.163ms
08-06 00:44:03.821    1904-1911/com.example.ebad.testing W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 210.005ms
08-06 00:44:03.832    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa6c42a30, tid 1936
08-06 00:44:03.838    1904-1917/com.example.ebad.testing I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1888(102KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 55% free, 834KB/1858KB, paused 3.470ms total 295.680ms
08-06 00:44:03.892    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-06 00:44:03.932    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
08-06 00:44:03.959    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-06 00:44:03.959    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae1de500, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-06 00:44:03.970    1904-1917/com.example.ebad.testing W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 132.060ms
08-06 00:44:04.215    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-06 00:44:04.823    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-06 00:44:05.503    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-06 00:44:05.503    1904-1936/com.example.ebad.testing W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xae1de500, error=EGL_SUCCESS
08-06 00:44:24.394    1904-1911/com.example.ebad.testing W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.553ms
08-06 00:45:10.805    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://111.68.99.8 refused
08-06 00:45:10.805    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
08-06 00:45:10.805    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-06 00:45:10.805    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-06 00:45:10.805    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-06 00:45:10.805    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at com.example.ebad.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:82)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
08-06 00:45:10.806    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:181)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ ... 17 more
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:623)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.checkOpenAndCreate(Socket.java:687)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:847)
08-06 00:45:10.807    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ ... 17 more
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:608)
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ ... 22 more
08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
08-06 00:45:10.809    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ebad.testing, PID: 1904
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'org.apache.http.StatusLine org.apache.http.HttpResponse.getStatusLine()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.ebad.testing.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:86)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
08-06 00:45:13.333    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1904 SIG: 9
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ebad.testing" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the logcat output of the crash? That'd be helpful

Comment: You're having "trouble"--what is the nature of that trouble?

Comment: @StephenG Sir, I have added the logcat I would be really thankful if you help me thanks :)

Comment: @DaveNewton when I input the Enrollment and the password and press the login button for login the app crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on Login button, you obtain an "NetworkOnMainThreadException". This kind of exception is due to work with network on the UI thread.

You can use an Async Task or use some library to manage network comunication. I suggest you to use Volley library. It's quite easy to use.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Create inner class and extend AsyncTask to perform the login operation I  the background. 
Long running operations like network connections should be executed off the UI thread..

Answer (score 0):

From the Logcat:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://111.68.99.8 refused
```

This means that the server did not accept your connection.

Re-type your permissions (in AndroidManifest.xml), as its likely that you have some problem there. Also, edit your question and post it there, we could help if we can see it entirely.

## Edit:

While you should not perform network operations on main threads (or User Interfaces), that does not seem to be the main problem.

`08-06 00:45:10.808    1904-1904/com.example.ebad.testing W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

Comment: I have added the androidMainfest.xml

Comment: @Ebadali check the edit, search for the error. It is most likely permission issue. I suggest on erasing the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` then manually writting it again, inside, and as the first element in the application element

Comment: well Sir,I don't know what is really the problem in it... I have edited this code according to my need but I don't much about httpclient and stuff..

Comment: I have edited the manifest.xml manually but still app is crashing can we chat in chat room or something to discuss the problem thanks.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just browse Stackoverflow and try to help where I can during working hours, so I wont use the chat. From my local attemps here, I did note that I had long delays, and that the result was correct. You seem to be having some other issue.... are you testing from a device or from the AVD? Also, access the link in the phone browser, to see if the host allows for mobile access of data.